# Magento website - sort by option: upper and lower arrow is bind with sorting data, need to remove upper and lower arrow only

Tags: javascript, html, css, magento

Upper and lower arrow symbol need to be removed. Here is my HTML code which is combined with JS.

```
<div class="wrap-select">
      <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
           <option value="http://localhost/purcheasy/phones.html?dir=asc&amp;order=position" selected="selected">Position</option>
           <option value="http://localhost/purcheasy/phones.html?dir=asc&amp;order=name">Name</option>
           <option value="http://localhost/purcheasy/phones.html?dir=asc&amp;order=price">Price</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css to hide this arrow as below :

```css
.sort-by-switcher{display:none}
```

Or you can use jquery like :

```js
jQuery('.sort-by-switcher').remove();
```